# constructor @Builder de loombok en JPA query

Tags: jpa, builder

Quiero hacer una consulta con Spring boot usuando la anotacion @Builder de loombok, para crear constructores personalizados en la consulta.
@Query("select com.multiplos.cuentas.pojo.solicitud.SolicitudResponse.builder().identificacion(s.inversionista.persona.identificacion).build()")

Answer (score 0):

Constructor queries are a JPA thing, and will execute a constructor method for you. Lombok on the other hand requires multiple method calls, and isn't want JPA constructor methods are meant for. You are much better off giving a constructor method to the query to use; you will not gain anything I can see from forcing Lombok where it doesn't fit.

Alternatively, return the raw "s.inversionista.persona.identificacion" data and do it yourself in a stream on the output.